# Views resize after pushing a view controller

Tags: ios, view, resize, push, uistoryboard

I'm having a really strange behaviour. When my app starts everything is fine: the size of the views on screen are exactly the one specified in the storyboard. But just as I try to push a view controller its contents are scaled, so when I pop back the view is messed up.

Any clues?

[image: Screen Before/after Push/Pop] [image: Storyboard]

Comment: Some sample code would be helpful.

Comment: The "code" involved is just a push segue, with no custom code.

Answer (score 0):

**First** learn about `Autolayout`. Here is a good way to go

- [Autolayout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

**Second** I am giving you a trick which may work.

Click on viewController

[image: Extending Edges]

If you don't want your views to extend their edges to bottom or to the top deselect `Under top bars` and `Under Bottom bars`

Comment: I know how to use autolayout, but whenever I try to add a constraint to any view in that particular controller, Xcode crashes. D:
I even tried Extend Edges settings but without success.

Comment: XCode crashes? This is an issue! Anyway can you give me a screenshot of your views in the Document Outline?

Comment: Solved. I wasn't using the view hierarchy in a safe way. The view controller was an UICollectionViewController (the controller.view was the collectionView) so the views I put in the storyboard editor were not in a "context" I could control.